# Outlook Email Sending error

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am using Outlook 2007. Suddenly, for past few days, i am not able to send email using Outlook. When I try to send a email, it gives an error which says:

> Sending reported error (0x80042109): Outlook cannot connect to your (SMTP) email-server. If you continue to receive this message, contact your admin or ISP.

I searched web for similar errors and solutions but they were diverging and none helped. (I tried changing port of SMTP to other as suggested by some forum - 425, SSL. No Antivirus S/W is running on my PC either.)

My account settings use below standard ports:
POP: 110
SMTP: 25

Only thing that has changed between earlier state when it was working, and now not working is my ISP upgraded our internet pipe from 1MBits to 4 Mbits.

There are other users in my company using Outlook w/o any problems.

Comment: Have you phoned your ISP to find out if they are blocking the port? It's not as rare as some might think...

Comment: @Jaymz:Why would they suddenly do that. And there are other users in my company using Outlook w/o any problems.

Comment: Not sure why they would do it, or even if they did. You didn't mention in your question that other users on the same connection are ok, but you did state that that was the only thing to have changed before it stopped working. Are the other users using the same SMTP settings as you?

Comment: they might do that if you're infected with a spam-sending virus... (But indeed, then every user with the same connection would be blocked.)

Answer (score 0):

Check the SMTP settings on another computer that works, and manually copy them to yours. Also look at Windows Firewall to see if the port is blocked or needs an exception adding.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the 'real answer'. But just uninstalled Microsoft office and reinstalled it.
Now with same settings of  SMTP, everything is working fine. But still don't know what could have been the original problem.